# Running into an error with Javascript scaffolding application build in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I can't get this to run.

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name udaciMealsApp.controller:MenuCtrl
 * @description
 * # MenuCtrl
 * Controller of the udaciMealsApp
 */
angular.module('udaciMealsApp')
  .controller('MenuCtrl', function () {
    this.id = 'strawberry-pudding';
    this.name = 'Strawberry Pudding';
    this.img = 'strawberry-pudding.jpg';
    this.rating = 5;  
  });
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name udaciMealsApp
 * @description
 * # udaciMealsApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('udaciMealsApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <header>
  </header>
  <body ng-app="udaciMealsApp">
      <div class="container">
          <div ng-include="'views/menu.html'" ng-controller="MenuCtrl as menu">   </div>
      </div>
  <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/menu.js"></script>
      </body>
</html>
<div class="row">
    <div class="items-container">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>{{menu.name}}</h4>
            <p>Rating: {{menu.rating}}</p>
            <p>Image: {{menu.img}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have written in Angular 2 when it was first release though as I'm getting into some complex code I am having issues with Gulp.  I am using Yoeman, Bower, Gulp and Grunt with install with npm on a pre-existing application.  As I clone the project I'm following the instructions with everything installed but when I go to run my application I get:

```
 >gulp serve
 Working directory changed to C:\Develop\Angular
```

Again I am just trying to run the project to see I can use the tools to see my app. I have run the 'npm install' the 'bower install' and trying to serve with gulp.[image: here is what my project looks like][image]

Comment: Time to move to a recent CLI build. Why would you torture yourself like this?

Answer (score 0):

Install Node.js

type

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

now type

`ng new YouApplicationName`

move into the new folder  `YouApplicationName`

type

`ng serve`

open `http://localhost:4200` in your browser.

Copy your code into the new project.

Comment: The first couple applications I ran with ng but then working with the tools you were right I needed NodeJS.  Let me run some tests and see if this actually solves the problem but ng does not run.

Comment: That was it I needed to get the version 9 up to date on 12 at least to work on the CLI. Thank you.

Comment: Alright I still have an issue as error 'An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'' and ran the 'npm install' for the build-angular but still getting it.